# ember unit testing models

Tags: unit-testing, ember.js

I am trying to write unit tests for my ember application. Currently the test that model exist works but I want to test computed properties within model which are based on some other properties generated by mirage or returned from API calls. My concern is how shall I initialize or populate data for the model under unit testing?

Sample unit test code for my model: "user" is:

```
import { moduleForModel, test } from 'ember-qunit';

moduleForModel('user', 'Unit | Model | User', {
    needs: ['model:account']
});
```

Now I want to write a test where I can use:

```
let model = this.subject();
```

And then I shall be able to access the properties injected by mirage. But how can I do that here? I did not find anything on documentation. Please help

Answer (score 2):

There is no first-class API for this in Mirage at the moment, though it is one of our top feature requests.

For now, you can use [something like this](https://gist.github.com/samselikoff/b00b5a190321c8236ee0e0fab200bf65) to push some Mirage-created data into your Ember Data store.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, will look into it. So if I am understanding it correctly, if I want to unit test a component like we do with acceptance test, I can generate data like this and then my components can leverage it?

Comment: Yep you could generate data from Mirage, then serialize it & push it directly into Ember Data's store, so your unit tests can work with Ember Data models